# Are environment variables expanded when searching PATH?

Tags: windows, batch-file

This question expands on the comments on [this deleted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30628893/886887).  I claimed that an unexpanded variable reference in the PATH would not be expanded when searching for an executable, but Ken said he didn't see the same behaviour that I did.

Note that the ordinary situation is subtly but critically different: subject to certain conditions, environment variables are automatically expanded when the PATH environment variable is built from the information in the registry.  I'm talking about the case where, for one reason or another, this hasn't happened, so the actual environment block of the `cmd.exe` process contains a PATH which still has environment variable references in it.

Here is the code I built to test this behaviour:

```
md test1
echo echo hello! > test1\test1.cmd

set TESTPATH=%cd%\test1

set percent=%%

set PATH=c:\windows\system32;c:\windows;c:\windows\system32\Wbem;%percent%TESTPATH%percent%

set PATH

set TESTPATH

test1

cmd /c test1

start test1.cmd
```

and this is the result on my machine:

```
C:\working\testpath>test

C:\working\testpath>md test1

C:\working\testpath>echo echo hello!  1>test1\test1.cmd

C:\working\testpath>set TESTPATH=C:\working\testpath\test1

C:\working\testpath>set percent=%

C:\working\testpath>set PATH=c:\windows\system32;c:\windows;c:\windows\system32\
Wbem;%TESTPATH%

C:\working\testpath>set PATH
Path=c:\windows\system32;c:\windows;c:\windows\system32\Wbem;%TESTPATH%
PATHEXT=.COM;.EXE;.BAT;.CMD;.VBS;.VBE;.JS;.JSE;.WSF;.WSH;.MSC;.py;.pyw

C:\working\testpath>set TESTPATH
TESTPATH=C:\working\testpath\test1

C:\working\testpath>test1
'test1' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

C:\working\testpath>cmd /c test1
'test1' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

C:\working\testpath>start test1.cmd
The system cannot find the file test1.cmd.
```

What is the expected behaviour?  Does it vary depending on the version of Windows and/or other factors?

Comment: Nicely done. I guess we were both right. :-) (Not about my posted answer to the linked question being incorrect - you were right about that aspect.)

Comment: @KenWhite: does my test code behave differently for you than it does for me?  (If not, perhaps I had just misinterpreted what you were saying?)

Comment: It'll be tomorrow before I get a chance to test it. It looks like you've done a good job of investigating; you'll make it easy to do so.

Comment: cmd.exe implements its own search in `cmd!SearchForExecutable`, instead of calling `kernel32!SearchPath`, or indirectly by passing the command line to `CreateProcess` (it finds and passes the fully qualified path in `lpApplicationName`). Unlike `SearchPath`, cmd's search strips quotes from each tokenized directory (quotes shouldn't be used in `PATH` anyway) and also tries appending the `PATHEXT` extensions. FWIW, I scanned over the assembly in the Windows 7 version of this function; it only calls `cmd!GetEnvVar` twice -- once for `PATH` and once for `PATHEXT` -- confirmed via breakpoint.

Comment: @eryksun: hmmm.  What does `start` do?  I would expect it to invoke ShellExecuteEx - I wonder if that uses yet another implementation?

Comment: OK, I happened to already have a program that passes its command line to CreateProcess, so using that in the test code from the question I was able to confirm that (on my machine) CreateProcess doesn't expand the PATH when searching it either.  So while CreateProcess is different from cmd!SearchForExecutable, the differences aren't relevant as far as this question is concerned.

Comment: The `start` command also calls `cmd!SearchForExecutable`. cmd always tries `ShellExecuteEx` if `CreateProcess` fails, whether or not you use `start`. However, with `start` if `SearchForExecutable` fails it passes the original command to `ShellExecuteEx`, which gives full control to the Windows shell, such as for running `App Paths` commands.

Comment: @eryksun: Where do you get those assembly listings from? I would like to take a look at they!

Comment: @Aacini, Microsoft has a public symbol server that you can use with its debuggers such as WinDbg, cdb, and kd.

Answer (score 1):

There are two entirely different points of view in this question:

- Q: How to expand the values of variables embedded in another one? This point is not specific to PATH variable, but works on anyone.

A: Enclose the names of the variables in exclamation marks and enable delayed expansion when you want to expand such values:

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

set TESTPATH=%cd%\test1
set "PATH=c:\windows\system32;c:\windows;c:\windows\system32\Wbem;^!TESTPATH^!"
set PATH
echo PATH=%PATH%
```

- Q: Does cmd.exe such delayed expansion when it use PATH to locate an executable file?

A: No. cmd.exe uses the values in PATH variable as they appear, with no further processing. Any special character that may appear in PATH, like percents or exclamation-marks, are taking literally.

Comment: The intent of the question was your second bullet point, though not *necessarily* restricted to `cmd.exe`, e.g., if Explorer expanded variables in the PATH that would also be interest.

Comment: Your first bullet point would be relevant except your solution is kind of back to front; the scenario is that PATH contains unexpanded references - in the percent-sign format - and we want to expand them.

Comment: Yes I understand this point, but I posted the first bullet precisely to have a reference base when the second bullet point is discussed. I think that in this way is easier to undersand the reason because an embedded %value% is not _further_ expanded.

Comment: cmd does do some processing on the values from `PATH`: it strips quotes. In contrast, Windows `SearchPath` (and thus `CreateProcess`) treats the quotes as a literal component of the path.